# Find period of power sequence $a^k \mod m$, with $a, m$ not coprime

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a, m$ be positive integers and $m > 1$. I'm interested in the sequence $(a^k)_{k 
\in \mathbb{N_0}} \mod m$. Since there are only $m$ different values that can occur in the sequence and since $a^k = a \cdot a^{k-1}\ \ \forall k > 0$ is only dependent on the previous element, I conclude that there exist $i, C \leq m$, such that $a^{k + C} = a^k\ \ \forall k \geq i$.

Example: $a = 2, m = 12$, we get the sequence $1, 2, 4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8... \mod 12$ with $x = 2, C = 2$.

Given $a$ and $m$, I want to algorithmically find some $i$ and $C$ with the above property. I'm especially interested in the case where $gcd(a,m) \neq 1$, since otherwise a trivial solution is $i = 0, C = \phi(m)$ according to [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), if I'm not mistaken. The obvious algorithm is naive in that it just evaluates the sequence element by element and stops as soon as it hits a duplicate. I'm sure we can do better than $O(m)$ exponentiations by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and factorizing $m$ or something, but since I don't have a math background it's a bit hard for me to put my finger on it.

The ultimate goal is to evaluate "exponential-tower"-type expressions of the form ${a_1}^{{a_2}^{a_3^{a_4^{\ldots}}}}$ modulo some prime $p$, as asked in [an algorithm question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367824/how-to-compute-an-exponential-tower-modulo-a-prime/21368784#21368784) I tried to contribute my two cents there by applying some observations, but I'm personally interested in this problem and pretty sure the algorithm can be improved if we can solve the particular problem of finding the cycle length faster.

If somebody has another general idea of solving the exponential-tower problem, that's very interesting as well and I'd love to hear it, but it's not the primary point of this question :)

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Carmichael_function

Comment: @Iab yeah but that, too, requires coprime $a $ and $ m $.I was looking for a reduction to let me apply the concept to the general case, like the one provided in the answer here.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the co-prime as prime

Comment: @Iab Euler's theorem already works for non-prime moduli, fortunately :)

Comment: do you realize the advantage Carmichael function over  Euler's Totient Theorem

Comment: @Iab I figured the difference was that phi could be a proper multiple of carmichael. That doesn't really give an asymptotic algorithmic advantage though. Please correct me if  I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick fairly obvious result that seems to fit is the following. Consider the sequence of greatest common divisors $d_k=\gcd(a^k,m)$. Because $m$ is fixed, this sequence will stabilize (sooner rather than later). Let $k_0$ be the first integer with the property that
$d_{k_0}=d_{k_0+1}$.

Starting from the index $k_0$ the powers $a^k$ are thus all divisible by $d=d_{k_0}$. The question is then: which multiple of $d$ are they? We easily see that $\gcd(a,m/d)=1$. If $a^k\equiv b_kd\pmod m$, we see that for $k\ge k_0$
$$
b_{k+1}\equiv b_k\cdot a\pmod{m/d}.
$$
All this implies that the period will be a factor of $\phi(m/d)$.

Thus an answer (but not the best possible one) is:

- $k=k_0$,
- $C=\phi(m/d)$, with $d=\gcd(a^N,m)$ for all large integers $N$.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately I can't come up with fairly obvious results like this in next to no time :) Glad Stack Exchange exists. Nice observation, that looks very useful.

Comment: If you know the prime factorization of both $a$ and $m$, it is easy to find $k_0$ by examining the multiplicities of the common prime factors. If a prime $p$ appear with multiplicity $n_a$ in $a$, and with multiplicity $n_m$ in $m$, then for $k\ge k_p:=n_m/n_a$ we have that $a^k$ is divisible by $p^{n_m}$. Let $k_0$ be the maximum of the numbers $k_p$, with $p$ ranging over the common factors.

Comment: In your example case $a^2=4$ has reached the maximal gcd with $m=12$: $d=\gcd(8,12)=\gcd(4,12)=4$. As you observed all the entries were multiples of $4$ after the second. Here the predicted period $\phi(m/d)=\phi(12/4)=\phi(3)=2$ is precise. But that's because $m/d$ is a prime (power), and $a$ happens to be a primitive root. If you can factor $m/d$, you can replace $\phi$ with the Carmichael function.

Comment: factorizing $a$ and $m$ is actually already faster than the expected $\Theta(m)$ brute-force approach. That's brings it down at least by a factor of $\Omega(m^{1/2})$, which is very nice.

Comment: Okay, now one point I don't really understand: So basically you define $b_k = a^k / d$, correct? So since $b_{k+1}d = a^{k+1} = a \cdot a^k = a \cdot b^kd$. Now if we factor out $d$, we get $b_{k+1} \equiv b_k \cdot a \pmod{m / d}$. Am I following what you did there? Now how exactly does this imply that the period will divide $\phi(m/d)$? I assume I just overlooked something, but it's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: Oh, I see, because of Euler's theorem we have $b_{k + \phi(m/d)} \equiv b_k \cdot a^{\phi(m/d)} \equiv b_k \pmod{m/d}$, so $a^{k + \phi(m/d)} \equiv a^k \pmod{m/d}$, but how can we conclude that $a^{k + \phi(m/d)} \equiv a^k \pmod{m}$? Sorry if that sounds stupid, still struggling with basic modular arithmetics :/

Comment: If $a\equiv b\pmod n$, then $ca\equiv ca\pmod {cn}$. Here $b_k\equiv b_{k+\phi(m/d)}\pmod{m/d}$, so
$$a_k=b_kd\equiv b_{k+\phi(m/d)}d=a_{k+\phi(m/d)}\pmod {dm/d)}.$$

Comment: Nice, okay great, I'll leave you in peace now :) Have a good one!

Comment: So, what can we say about the power tower ${a_1}\uparrow {a_2}\uparrow...\uparrow{a_n}$ mod m ? How many terms (depending on m) must the tower contain that adding any terms on the top does not change the result ? And how can it be proven that EVERY power tower becomes "stable" at this stage or sooner ?

Comment: And which strategy guarantees the correct result for all power towers and all natural numbers m ?

Comment: @Peter: Let $m_i$ the sequence of inner moduli. Algorithmically, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367824/how-to-compute-an-exponential-tower-modulo-a-prime/21368784#21368784 for an algorithm to evaluate the tower (i.e. figure out a valid sequence $m_i$). I think we can improve the runtime if we make use of [this property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) of the Carmichael function, because $m_{i+1} = \lambda(m_i)$ seems to decrease very fast and maybe it's even the optimal sequence. In any case, $m_{i+1} < m_i$ for all i, so ...

Comment: ... after $m$ steps we can be sure that the modulus is $1$ and thus the tower has become "stable" if you so want.

Comment: Thanks, Niklas! Do you also know an implementation in PARI ? If not, I will try to implement it myself.

Comment: @Peter: Nope, but let me know if you finished it or find any problems with the approach :) Preferrably on Stack Overflow rather than here.